# Display `pretty output` of directory content from array

Tags: php, iterator, directory, recursive-datastructures

I'm using the following code to get an array of directories and their sub-directories where each contain file type extension: png. It works great but I need to be able to output the results of the array in a list style format e.g.

```
* Test
  -> test2.png
  -> test1.png
  * subfolder
    -> test3.png
    * sub sub folder
      -> test4.png
```

etc

Code:

```
$filter=".png";  
$directory='../test';  
$it=new RecursiveDirectoryIterator("$directory");
foreach(new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it) as $file){  
    if(!((strpos(strtolower($file),$filter))===false)||empty($filter)){  
        $items[]=preg_replace("#\\\#", "/", $file);  
    }
}
```

Example array of results:

```
array (
  0 => '../test/test2.png',
  1 => '../test/subfolder/subsubfolder/test3.png',
  2 => '../test/subfolder/test3.png',
  3 => '../test/test1.png',
)
```

What would be the best way of achieving the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

In your if-clause, try:

```
$items[]=preg_replace("#\\\#", "/", $file->getPathName());
```

This should give you an output close to the one you desire. However, `getPathName` outputs absolute paths.

Comment: Thanks.

But I'm after displaying it as formatted text on a website e.g.

Directory->
   - Image
   - Image
   - Directory ->
        - Image
        - Image

So one can see a structural representation of the data.

Comment: Ah, okay. Misunderstood you there.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display files before directories, then you can't do it simply in a loop, because you won't know if more files would come later.

You need to aggregate the data in a tree (array of arrays indexed by path component) or sort it.

```
$components = explode('/',$path);
$file = array_pop($components);
$current = $root;
foreach($components as $component) {
  if (!isset($current[$component])) $current[$component] = array();
  $current = &$current[$component];
}
$current[$file] = true;
```

It should give you structure such as:

```
array(
  'test'=>array(
      'test1.png'=>true,
      'subfolder'=>array(
      …
```

That will be straightforward to work with (of course that kinda defeats the purpose of `RecursiveDirectoryIterator`. You could get the same by recursively using regular `DirectoryIterator`).

Or if you sort paths by depth (write your comparison function), then you'll be able to output it simply by printing last path component with appropriate indentation.